# Legally buy Excel 2010 only

Tags: microsoft-office

Where can I legally buy a digital download version of Excel 2010?

I have read that if I download it from the Microsoft Store I can only install it on one computer, and never on another computer!

Is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you purchase a license for Excel 2010, you may install it on 1 computer (Home & Student licences can be installed on [up to three PCs](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/pd/Excel-Home-and-Student-2010/productID.216446900/vip.true)).

If you want to install it on an **additional** (2 installations) computer, you need an **additional** licence.

If you just want to install your existing, single license on another computer, you're very much allowed to do so (at least I didn't find contradicting information on the Microsoft Store).

Comment: does the home/student version have full functionality of the excell 2010? Other than the right to not use it for revenue making...?

Comment: @suntoryy One of the key differences is that the Home & Student version can be installed on **up to 3 computers**, while the standard version can only be installed on 1 computer (I guess).

Comment: @suntoryy: Yes.  The other difference os the programs it contains (it does not have Outlook, for example).

Comment: @paradroid The question was about the standalone version of Excel (which also has a *Standard* and a *Home and Student* version).

Comment: Oh, okay.  I didn't know that.

Answer (score -1):

"Where can I legally buy a digital download version of excell 2010?": This is your question and ":Through Microsoft" is the answer.

As to the number of licenses, that's a different question, and they will explain that with your purchase.

Comment: well i bought it and clicked the 3 computers (transferable to other computers option) but that's mentioned no-where in the invoice.

Comment: @suntoryy - Your statements made no sense.  The location would be on the same website as you purchased it.